# Regex Substitution to add a class to a specific html tag

Tags: regex, wp-cli

I need to do a regex find-replace on the post content of a wordpress site in order to change all existing `<h4>` tags to `<h2>` tags.  I then need to style the `<h4>` tags to look like `<h2>` tags.

My plan was to add a class to the new `<h2>` tags...

`<h4> Some poorly written html </h4>`
becomes
`<h2 class="pseudo-h4"> Some poorly written html </h2>`

I feel like this should be doable with regex, but I just cannot seem to grok the more advanced parts of regex.  My current working approach is to use this regex `(?<=h4)(.+class=")` to capture the 'class=' part of any h4 opening tag and then use `$1pseudo-h4`  as the substitution string.  Once that is done I can go back and replace all h4s without regex because those which are "pseudo-h4s" will already be marked by the class.

I have a few problems...

1 - wp-cli is hanging when I try to run this on wp_posts. Maybe this is normal?
2 - `$1pseudo-h4`  with a space on the end is needed prevent my class from concatenating with the next class, but when i pass the argument with a space on the end i get "unknown --regex  parameter"
3 - In my tester it worked, but I dont actually know why this pattern wont match the tag of a previous element, for instance...

`<h4>Sup<h4><p class="extra-cheese">Bla bla<p>`
my lookbehind should see the `<h4>` and .+ should go through as many characters as it needs to hit the "class=" section right?

Comment: Can you [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and replace? Search for [`<h4>(.*?)</h4>`](https://regex101.com/r/giUIO2/1) or [`<h4[^>]*>(.*?)</h4>`](https://regex101.com/r/giUIO2/2) and replace with `<h2...>$1</h2>`

Comment: After sleeping on the problem and looking at your suggestions I realized I had been thinking about captures wrong.  

I modified your selector slightly to 
[<h4([^>]*) class="(.*?>.*?</)h4>](https://regex101.com/r/sLczMI/1) and [<h2$1 class="pseudo-h4 $2h2>](https://regex101.com/r/sLczMI/1) and I think this is going to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @JeremyDixon! Yes, sleeping on problem helps me too quite often. :)